# Chartjs responsive size

Tags: css, reactjs, canvas

I would like to resize the font size when i have small width with my char. I use ChartJs with Line type.
I have this when the width of canvas is 100% (1500px):
[image]
But when i change the size of canvas 50% (750px) i have this :
[image]

The text is not possible to read he is very small, I would the font size don't change . It's possible to make this ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a font size in the chart configuration, that should do it.

```
var options = {
   scales: {
    x: {
        ticks: {
            font: {
                size: 12,
            }
        }
     }
   }
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).